# Spaces are appearing on the right and left side of a Scroll View android?

Tags: android

[image] [image]I am developing an android application. On the preview the view is presanting the way I have set it but when I run it on a device I am seeing spaces on it right and left side.
Screen shots are attached for the better understanding of the problem.

Below is the code of my layout.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="------"
    >

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/screen_background">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/telephone_number"
                android:id="@+id/telephonNumberTextView"
                android:phoneNumber="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/phoneNumberEditText"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:textAlignment="textStart" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/telephone_extension"
                android:id="@+id/telephoneExtensionTextView"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/telephoneExtensionEditText"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/email_id"
                android:id="@+id/emailIdTextView"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/emailIdEditText"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/problem_type"
                android:id="@+id/problemTypeTextView"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"/>

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="@string/fetch_problem_types"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonback"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/location"
                android:id="@+id/locationTextView"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/locationEditText"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/brief_desc"
                android:id="@+id/briefDescTextView"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/briefDescEditText"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/doc_desc"
                android:id="@+id/docDescTextView"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/docDescEditText"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/approval_memo"
                android:id="@+id/approvalMemoTextView"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/approvalMemoEditText"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/requester_Name"
                android:id="@+id/requesterNameTextView"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/requesterNameEditText"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="@string/submit_button_title"
                android:id="@+id/submitButton"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonback"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Whether you are displaying this layout as fragment?

Comment: Try by removing    android:layout_gravity="center" in scroll view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (most probably) lies in the top level XML. I assume you posted only the `content.xml` which is included my `activity_main.xml`, because I can't see the Floating Action Button.

I guess you used the build-in generator to create layouts for you and edited the `content.xml` one. The paddings are defined inside the `activity_main.xml` one. Delete them and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks qmar. Yes problem was in the content.xml. Resolved now :).

Answer (score 0):

Remove layout android:layout_margin="5dp" in Email Id EditText

```
<EditText
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
  android:ems="10"
  android:id="@+id/emailIdEditText"
  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:background="@drawable/edittext"
  android:paddingLeft="4dp" />
```

Comment: I think the OP was not asking about the email field, but the margin in general.